# SQL: grouped aliases for subqueries returning multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, alias

I have a sql query containing a subquery from which I'd like two columns to get returned.
For the moment it looks like this :

```
SELECT A,
       B,
       CASE
         WHEN B IS NULL THEN NULL
         ELSE (
           SELECT first_column
           FROM   TABLE
           WHERE  TABLE.id = A.id
         )
       END AS TABLE_first_column,
       CASE
         WHEN B IS NULL THEN NULL
         ELSE (
           SELECT second_column
           FROM   TABLE
           WHERE  TABLE.id = A.id
         )
       END AS TABLE_second_column
FROM   OTHER_TABLE
...
```

Up above the subqueries are identical, except that they don't return the same column.
I was wondering if it was possible to somehow have only one subquery returning 2 columns, and have an alias for each respective column, something like this :

```
SELECT A,
       B,
       CASE
         WHEN B IS NULL THEN NULL
         ELSE (
           SELECT first_column,
                  second_column
           FROM   TABLE
           WHERE  TABLE.id = A.id
         )
       END AS (TABLE_first_column, TABLE_second_column)
FROM   OTHER_TABLE
...
```

Is it possible to do this somehow ?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using. I'm guessing it's Oracle.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Just did. It's SQL Server in this case but I'm also working on DB2 so I'm curious if this is doable on other DBMSs.

Answer (score 0):

If your `TABLE` and `OTHER_TABLE` tables are related via `id`, you could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  A,
  B,
  CASE
    WHEN B IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE t1.first_column
  END AS TABLE_first_column,
  CASE
    WHEN B IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE t1.second_column
  END AS TABLE_second_column
FROM OTHER_TABLE t
LEFT JOIN "TABLE" t1 ON t.id = t1.id
```

Comment: Thing is I'm already using a CTE as the source, so I can't really use joins in the main query.

Comment: @RaekhVoid . . . Your comment doesn't make sense.  CTEs can be used in `JOIN`s.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thing is I'm not asking about joins, but about aliases. I'm not looking to fix the problem using joins, but by finding a way to have multiple aliases. If that's not possible, I'll do it in another way. Otherwise no. But so far that's not answering my question.